# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow' has no attribute 'TFE_Py_RegisterExceptionClass'

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, time-series, recurrent-neural-network

I am trying to develop some time-series sequence prediction, using the latest resources available. To that end, I did check the example code from TensorFlow time-series, but I'm getting this error:

```
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow' has no attribute 'TFE_Py_RegisterExceptionClass'
```

I'm using Anaconda. The current environment is Python 3.5 and TensorFlow 1.2.1. Also tried TensorFlow 1.3, but nothing changed.

Here is [the code I'm trying to run](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/timeseries/examples/predict.py). I did not find anything useful related to the issue on Google. Any ideas on how to solve it?

Comment: This error signals that a C function called `TFE_Py_RegisterExceptionClass` is not available when python interpreter tries to invoke it. This function normally comes from a compiled native library part of tensorflow (.so if you are on Linux). If your python interpreter is unable to find it, my first guess would be a bad installation of tensorflow. I just tried this example on a freshly installed tf 1.3 in docker (with python 2 and python3) and it worked just fine (after installing python3 versions of matplotlib and python3-tk)

Comment: Thanks. I tried to remove/clean some environments from anaconda and install all again and it work this time.

Comment: I had the same error when the tensorflow and tensorflow-estimator were different versions

Answer (score 0):

As Conan.Net wrote:

> I tried to remove/clean some environments from anaconda and install
>   all again and it work this time.

This solution worked for me as well, so though not ideal, it will solve the problem. If you are using anaconda, it might happen when installing some packages and then removing them (e.g. tensorflow vs tensorflow-gpu) leaves some dependencies hanging. In my case, I used:

```
conda remove --name py2_tf_gpu --all
```

then

```
conda create --name py2_tf_gpu python=2 anaconda pandas numpy scipy jupyter 
source activate py2_tf_gpu
pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade tensorflow-gpu
```

pip currently installs a later(1.4) than anaconda(1.3) version and I had need for it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the version of tensorflow doesn't match the version of keras.

Using a lower version of keras solve this problem