# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow' has no attribute 'TFE_MonitoringNewCounter0'

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, rasa-nlu, rasa-core, rasa

I'm using Rasa for a chatbot project and recently completed the installation. When I try to train my bot using the 'rasa train' command, it shows me this error and I cant seem to find a way to solve it.

I've reinstalled tensorflow as suggested on another forum, but it didnt make a difference

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "c:\users\rithesh\anaconda3_update\envs\tf_gpu\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "c:\users\rithesh\anaconda3_update\envs\tf_gpu\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\Rithesh\Anaconda3_update\envs\tf_gpu\Scripts\rasa.exe\__main__.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "c:\users\rithesh\anaconda3_update\envs\tf_gpu\lib\site-packages\rasa\__main__.py", line 69, in main
    set_log_level(log_level)
  File "c:\users\rithesh\anaconda3_update\envs\tf_gpu\lib\site-packages\rasa\utils\common.py", line 68, in set_log_level
    update_tensorflow_log_level()
  File "c:\users\rithesh\anaconda3_update\envs\tf_gpu\lib\site-packages\rasa\utils\common.py", line 87, in update_tensorflow_log_level
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "c:\users\rithesh\anaconda3_update\envs\tf_gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
    from tensorflow._api.v1 import compat
  File "c:\users\rithesh\anaconda3_update\envs\tf_gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\_api\v1\compat\__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from tensorflow._api.v1.compat import v1
  File "c:\users\rithesh\anaconda3_update\envs\tf_gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\_api\v1\compat\v1\__init__.py", line 626, in <module>
    child_package_str=('tensorflow_estimator.python.estimator.api.estimator'))
  File "c:\users\rithesh\anaconda3_update\envs\tf_gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\tools\component_api_helper.py", line 56, in package_hook
    child_pkg = importlib.import_module(child_package_str)
  File "c:\users\rithesh\anaconda3_update\envs\tf_gpu\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "c:\users\rithesh\anaconda3_update\envs\tf_gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_estimator\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from tensorflow_estimator._api.v1 import estimator
  File "c:\users\rithesh\anaconda3_update\envs\tf_gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_estimator\_api\v1\estimator\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from tensorflow_estimator._api.v1.estimator import experimental
  File "c:\users\rithesh\anaconda3_update\envs\tf_gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_estimator\_api\v1\estimator\experimental\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from tensorflow_estimator.python.estimator.canned.dnn import dnn_logit_fn_builder
  File "c:\users\rithesh\anaconda3_update\envs\tf_gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_estimator\python\estimator\__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
    import tensorflow_estimator.python.estimator.estimator_lib
  File "c:\users\rithesh\anaconda3_update\envs\tf_gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_estimator\python\estimator\estimator_lib.py", line 22, in <module>
    from tensorflow_estimator.python.estimator.canned.baseline import BaselineClassifier
  File "c:\users\rithesh\anaconda3_update\envs\tf_gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_estimator\python\estimator\canned\baseline.py", line 67, in <module>
    from tensorflow_estimator.python.estimator import estimator
  File "c:\users\rithesh\anaconda3_update\envs\tf_gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_estimator\python\estimator\estimator.py", line 37, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.eager import monitoring
  File "c:\users\rithesh\anaconda3_update\envs\tf_gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\monitoring.py", line 31, in <module>
    create=pywrap_tensorflow.TFE_MonitoringNewCounter0,
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow' has no attribute 'TFE_MonitoringNewCounter0'
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you read this already?
[AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow' has no attribute 'TFE_Py_RegisterExceptionClass'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46010571/attributeerror-module-tensorflow-python-pywrap-tensorflow-has-no-attribute-t)
In my experience a clean conda environment goes a long way. Also the order in which you type your conda install commands matters.